# Edit form field in Django on click and update in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

Here's what I am looking for.
I have an UpdateView, which renders the form from CreateView with fields loaded from database. Instead my edit form has **readonly** html attribue. So what I need is to drop readonly on click on the form field and when i enter new value it will be automaticaly updated when cursos moves to the next field.

How do i handle POST actions with out submit button?

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript(Jquery) to do so, `blur` event

EDITED: about CSRF verification,see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

about `$.post` see:https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

template.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myinput").blur(function(){
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
  });

  $.post('/link-to-fun/',{"value":value});
  }); 
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="myinput">
```

url.py

write a special url(/link-to-fun/) to function in views.py

```
url(r'^link-to-fun$', views.change_db_value),
```

views.py

```
def change_db_value(request):
    value = request.POST.get('value','')
    # database operation
```

Comment: if veto down,tell me reason. I will change my answer and improve myself. Thx

Comment: I did - You've changed from `$.get` to `$.post` (which makes sense), but you're not handling CSRF so I don't think Django will even allow this without declaring it safe (but you *should* make it safe). A mouseout event is the wrong solution for this (blur seems more appropriate), and your method to binding it is also seriously outdated. Lastly, I have no idea why you're providing a callback which just returns the server response.

Comment: you can post CSRF value together

Comment: Yes *you can*, but *your answer didn't*

Comment: OK,thanks for your suggestion. I changed my answer ^_^. I am a newbie and There are a lot of things need to learn